# Run JS file only on activation and deactivation of plugin in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, paypal

I have created [custom Divi module](https://github.com/angelleye/divi-paypal) and then convert it to the plugin. Divi page builder saves **local storage variables** so my module is not displaying in the modules list until I clears local storage.
I have added JS file that clears storage and its works fine.
but I want that js runs only at activation and deactivation.

**Below is Plugin activation code**

```
 function angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install()
    {    
            // trigger our function that registers PayPal for Divi plugin.     
            angelleye_setup_for_paypal_divi();                        
    }
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install' );
```

This is how I adding my js file in plugin.

```
function paypal_divi_clear_local_storage () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'paypal_divi_clear_local_storage', plugins_url('assets/js/clear_local_storage.js',__FILE__ ));        
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'paypal_divi_clear_local_storage', 9999 );
```

Here add_action is not calling from the activation function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create new function that add your custom option and call function on activation hook:

**New Function**

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation' );
function my_plugin_activation() {
  add_option( 'my_plugin_activation','just-activated' );
}
```

Set below code on time of init action this will work on activation time:

```
function mycustom_plugin()
{

    if( is_admin() && get_option( 'my_plugin_activation' ) == 'just-activated' ) 
   {
       delete_option( 'my_plugin_activation' );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'paypal_divi_clear_local_storage', plugins_url('assets/js/clear_local_storage.js',__FILE__ ));
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'mycustom_plugin' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you.

Please include these lines in your plugin file..

```
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin_Name
*/


class Plugin_Name       /* Define the name of the plugin or file */
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'enqueue_js_files'));
  }

  public function enqueue_js_files()
  {
    wp_register_script('clear_local_storage', plugins_url('clear_local_storage.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('clear_local_storage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to run js only 2 times, Once when plugin activate and second when plugin deactivate.

Comment: I am not sure, it will work or not, as i have not tested, but you can test for once.

Comment: Replace "add_action" line with "register_activation_hook" & "register_deactivation_hook" in my code. I know i am talking foolish, but lets try for once.